# Please add "What topics can I ask about here?" to the bottom or top of the Question Editor

Tags: feature-request

IMHO adding this specific link (that we have for all different sites in the Stack Exchange network), would be a good idea in general, and a great help for any new members [of any section] as they can directly see and understand what is expected of them, what topics are allowed on **that specific site** and possibly see where (which site) they can ask their questions. (Some sites such as [crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [datascience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) have decent explanations for newbies on what is allowed to be asked there and which other sites they might need to use instead if the topics doesn't suit their needs)

Currently if anyone needs /wants to see this link or know about any of this, needs to navigate to the Help Center usually by initiating asking a new question and click on the link on the sidebar), and then look for the link. This is cumbersome at best and it doesn't have to be like this specially when this can potentially decrease the number of off-topic/unrelated questions and in turn closed questions for this very reason.

Comment: Note that [stats.se] and [datascience.se] are not "sections" of Stack Overflow. They are different sites in the Stack Exchange network of sites.

Comment: yes,  I know, I just said it for the of lack of a better wording! (I tried to make it as simple as possible, I thought of sites, sister sites, etc but ultimately came up with sections which apparently wasnt the best choice of word!